# 5-24 Voltage Input to 5V/500mA Output

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, ldo

I'm looking for an IC with fixed 5V output voltage and a maximum of 500mA (USB standard). I've searched and found some buck converters and LDOs the problem is because of their drop voltage, when Vin=5V then Vout<5V. Is it possible to achieve a Vout=5V with a single IC? If not, what is the best way to achieve the step down needed plus the particular situation of Vin=Vout=5V?

Comment: Depends, can you allow a tiny voltage drop? If yes, then there are P-FET controllers which can do 100 % duty cycle.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a SEPIC (single-ended primary-inductor converter). As long as the input voltage is in its range it will maintain the output voltage even if it is greater than the input. For example you could set it for 10V and it will give you 10V with the input at for example 5V or 15V. I use them a lot they are very stable and not that expensive. You can go to your favorite supplier and look for SEPIC or Buck/Boost converters. These are basically a single IC but with an inductor and other components around it.